# Execute commands when system is started

Tags: 12.04, xorg, lightdm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to start applications at startup automatically?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-to-start-applications-at-startup-automatically)

How can I specify the commands which I want to execute when system is started?

So far I tried to write it in `.initrc`, `.xinitrc`, `.xprofile` but none of them seems working.

I use Ubuntu 12.04 and LightDM.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find what you need in this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247706/start-script-when-gnome-starts-up).

Other solution will be to create a script in `/etc/init.d` and use `update-rc.d`, but not sure this is what you are looking for...

Hope this help.